# How to change background color of fusionchart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I want to change backgound color of fusionchart from white to black. How can it be done? Also how change the font color in the chart?

[image]

Comment: Please check it here http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/basic-chart-configurations/border-and-background.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clearly defined** 
[Refer here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/basic-chart-configurations/border-and-background.html)

A chart’s background refers to the whole area on which a chart is drawn. The background of the chart is enclosed by a chart border. The chart border is a rectangle around the chart background.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Background Color attribute in the Chart Configuration `bgColor` and set it to #000000

You can read more here: http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/basic-chart-configurations/border-and-background.html#customizing-chart-background

Answer (score 0):

To change the background the color of fusion chart you need to use "bgColor" and "bgAlpha"

Refer to the below code -

```
{
"chart": {
    "bgColor": "#DDDDDD",
    "bgAlpha": "50"
}
```

}

To know more about it please [refer](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/border-and-background#customize-chart-background)

Demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw9ztdb0/)